# Reading a file into a Linked List in C

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I am having trouble with a certain aspect of my code in the C programming language. Here is the problem at hand. I have to read in a file that is formatted as so:

```
q    99  
z    8  
q    4
```

Each line starts with either q or z, followed by a tab, followed by a number. I want to store only the numbers that start on line q in a linked list.

I am able to isolate the lines starting with q, but my code separates the value 99 into two separate nodes 9 and 9. I am not sure how to fix this.

Any constructive help would be great, and be kind, I am new to the C language!

```
// Beginning of code reads the file in, and provides structure and
// function declarations
struct node *start = NULL;
char w;

while((w = fgetc(filep))!= EOF ) //filep is pointer to the file
{
    if(w=='z')
        break;
    else if(isdigit(w))
        push(&start, w); //push function creates the nodes
}

// rest of code has function definitions of push and print, creating
// and printing the linked list
```

Comment: It's because you get *single characters*. I suggest you read up on [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf),

Comment: `char w;` -->> `int w;` ... for a start ..

Answer (score 2):

You're currently reading character by character. `"99"` is made up of two characters.

An easy fix for this particular problem would be to use a function designed to parse formatted input like [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).
Here's an example of how to use it:

```
while (true) {
    char w;
    int v;

    int count = scanf(" %c %d", &w, &v);
    if (count != 2)
        break;

    if (w == 'q')
        push(&start, v);
}
```

Note that in the format string, I've included a leading space. This will make sure that before we get to the `%c`, we consume any leading whitespace. This whitespace would include the trailing newline from the previous line.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. I see your logic! I was wondering if there were any suggestions to use as the condition for the while loop. I am having difficulties coming up with the proper way, since fgetc has led me astray. I have been trying to use different conditional statements with EOF and the compiler has not been happy yet.

Comment: I'm currently using the inner test with the break to end the while loop.

Comment: Hmm, I am sorry, I don't seem to be following. The true seems to be giving the compiler some issues. When I attempt to run the while loop, the error:" undeclared first use of this function" error appears at this line. Do you know what might be the issue? And thank you for your patience in helping out a newbie C programmer.

Comment: You should be able to replace true with 1 or include stdbool.h.

Comment: The loop runs now, but it is infinite. This is why I thought to change the condition so it will eventually reach the end of the file. Something is amiss and I am not sure what it may be.